# Grouping SSRS tables in report

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I need a report presenting laboratory tests. I get several tests every day (different tables like Chem, Micro or Sub). I would like to be able to display them separately on each page - based on [SampleID] - but together with the corresponding categories (tables). So far, I was only able to display all the results on one page or grouped by tables, but then for example instead of 10 pages I have 20. How can I group it correctly?

[image]

The solution that interests me seems to be in this post [How can I have multiple tables on one SSRS page that represents one value in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68487914/how-can-i-have-multiple-tables-on-one-ssrs-page-that-represents-one-value-in-sql). But when I follow the directions I get an error code "The tablix ‘Tablix4’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members."

Comment: just create a row group that groups by sampleID and then set the rowgroup properties/pagebreak to "between"

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did, and it works, but only when the tables are in one row
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEMH9.png
, but I needs them underneath the other - in this case, the tables display on separate pages.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNeDo.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).